# Implementing multiple private blockchains?

Tags: implementation, blockchain

//This may be a silly question.
I am exploring blockchains and now working on some concept  project. For that I need to have multiple users (in millions), each maintaining their own blockchain. Unlike general implementations where every one contributes to a single public ledger. I found [Multichain](http://www.multichain.com/) which is the closest as it gets. Are there any other options? Also, does this sound like I am ruining the essence of blockchains with this?

Comment: This question is way too broad and the problem presented way too complex for a Q/A format like StackOverflow. It will cause discussions rather than yield answers. I recommend to delete it. I would vote to close it if it did not have a bounty on it, stopping me to do so. So I appeal to the author's common sense. The question is like: "Hey I want to make a grand invention which wins me a Nobel Prize, but don't want to do all the hard research work. Please do it for me so I can get the fame."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric version 1.0 will introduce channels, which will allow the creation of private channels within the fabric.

> "Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 introduces network **channels**, which are
>   private lines of communication between specific peers. Channels
>   restrict data dissemination, including channel membership, transaction
>   and state information, to peers on the same channel. Although any one
>   peer can belong to multiple channels, the peer cannot discover or 
>   communicate with peers across channels. This partitioning of data by
>   channel is defined by configuration chaincode and implemented by a
>   **gossip-based data dissemination** protocol."

You can read more about that in this pdf - https://jira.hyperledger.org/secure/attachment/10362/FabricOverview_draft1.pdf at ## 6. Channels and chains

Comment: :That should work I guess. Would you mind commenting on use of multiple blockchains. Imagine a platform, that let's you create your own blockchain to host any kind of transaction. Such that for 'x' members there's one parent blockchain and 'x' sidechains. These members can be part of other sidechains in the network too.
As there's no single public ledger in this setup, does that mean one should go for distributed database instead of blockchain in such a case?
Please don't be harsh on me if this sounds too dumb.

Comment: What is happening on this page? User renames existing datastructures in compsci and wants a generic implementation of it. Problem is, rename hijacks the name of a legitimate technology, which is stripped down of its effectiveness, by removing parts of the protocol(which i try to prove by asking for counterexamples). Then a corporate software, with same hijacked name is advertised and selected. This is evil practice here.

Answer (score 0):

No problem in making a million blockchains, but the problem is 'private blockchains'; there is not a single usecase that you can achieve with private chains but not git. 
Also since you mention 'public ledger' I suppose you shall be storing data on the blockchain which is not a good idea since it goes expensive pretty quickly.

Comment: Well the use case I have can be compared to git. I am not planning to store the actual data on blockchain, instead the data will be in a separate data lake with a copy of it in BC owner's infra and pointers to that will be stored in BC. This is so, because I don't want the BC to be vary heavy later.

Comment: @Amit What can you do with private blockchains that you cant with git? Why do you want to use blockchains?

Comment: Well my use case, when I thought about it, does not actually need multiple block chains. I am leaving this question open just for the community to comment on what can multiple block chains be used for and which platforms are providing this.